# Download of web page starts upon REST MERGE call

Tags: list, rest

I have a nested REST call, that first **GETS** *numClicked* attribute of an item, then increments it by one, and **MERGES** back to update the column with the newly incremented value. This is working correctly, but for some reason, after this MERGE is made, when you refresh or reopen the page to see if the column updated or not, it begins a download of the web page itself. This download will fail eventually, when it fails or you cancel it, upon refreshing again, the change has been made.

How do I stop this download? Code included below.

```
 function followLink(link, id){
    window.open(link);
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url:"/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('IconLinkList')/Items(" + id + ")",
        headers:{"Accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"},
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:'application/json; odata=verbose',
        success:function(data) {
            var results = data.d;
            console.log("/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('IconLinkList')/Items(" + id + ")");
            var temp = results.numClicks + 1;

            $.ajax({
                url: "/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('IconLinkList')/Items(" + id + ')',
                type: "MERGE",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    '__metadata': {
                        'type': 'SP.Data.IconLinkListListItem'
                    },
                    'numClicks': temp
                }),
                headers: {
                    "IF-MATCH": "*",
                    "X-HTTP-Method":"PATCH",
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                }
            }); 

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('IconLinkList')/Items(" + id + ")");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your browser or firewall doesn't like the "MERGE" request type...

Generally you use `POST` as the `type` with `MERGE` or `PATCH` (as you have used) as the `X-HTTP-Method`

Try changing your second $.ajax to:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('IconLinkList')/Items(" + id + ')',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.Data.IconLinkListListItem'
                },
                'numClicks': temp
            }),
            headers: {
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "X-HTTP-Method":"PATCH",
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            }
        }).fail(function(xhr) { console.log("Failed inner request: \n" + xhr.responseText });
```

Comment: The problem appears to persist, but I did make that change and am seeing the exact same behavior in the call, so I will leave it as a POST.

Comment: I wonder if it's something interfering with the async call -- try adding a .fail(function(xhr) { //inspect failure info -- xhr.responseText }) to your inner $.ajax (the one we modified)

Comment: fail:function(xhr){
        alert("failed");
       log(xhr.responseText);}

This function is not firing.

Comment: Note: When i refresh the list page and get the download, the console is giving me this.   **Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: ".../Lists/IconLinkList/AllItems.aspx".**

Comment: you put .fail after the closing paren on your $.ajax() function -- I've updated my example code to include this. Could you try commenting out your window.open statement and see if that changes anything also?

Comment: .fail is still not firing after the change and i commented the window.open out and it still happens when it is opened through <a> tag.  It is worth noting that this download file bug only occurs in Google Chrome,  not in FF or IE. I believe this may have to do with how the browsers handle the POST requests.

Comment: Something lingers when the column is updated with the POST request, because even when i do not have the list open as I trigger the update, when i next try to go to the list page, before it even navigates to the page it begins the page download.